# Git File push to remote undo

Tags: git

I have a file that I made changes to locally and then committed and pushed to remote.I actually realized that they were incorrect changes and want only that particular file to go back to its original state (and not undo entire commit), will git checkout filename work? or should I delete the file locally and pull from master?

Comment: No; you can only push commits.

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout HEAD -- file.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me (maybe for my particular situation but just posting incase it helps anyone!)-->
1) undo my change from file
2) do a diff between master file and my file copy to see if no differences 
3) commit and push 
the file disappeared from Pull Request Files Changed (which is what I wanted)

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your commit by performing any additional changes you may need and then commiting them with `git commit --ammed`. You could then use `git push --force origin` to "override" your previous commit.

Note that this may break any work other have done on top of this commit, so you should use it with great care.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file in your work tree back to its previous state using something like

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- path/to/file
```

(This assumes the file was broken in the most recent commit.  You could use `HEAD~2` instead of `HEAD^` to go back 2 commits, etc.)

Then you can treat this like any other change; if nothing else needs to be changed, you can go ahead and add/commit/push.

Since you have already pushed the original commit, I recommend you *not* use `--amend`.  Doing so would require a force push, which would then cause trouble for everyone else who has the ref in their clone of the repo.  It's possible to recover, so if you really want to coordinate with the whole team to slightly clean up the history, you *could*; but I doubt it would be worth it.